# Haskell probleme with Data.Map as Map

Tags: haskell

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map 

type Identifier = String

type Value = Float

data Store = Map Identifier Value

store = [("x", 1), ("y", 2)]

-- find in the store

findVar :: (Eq v) => v ->[(v,val)] -> Maybe val

findVar var [] = Nothing

findVar var ((v,val):xs) = if var == v then Just val else findVar var xs


data Expression =

    Literal Float

  | Addition Expression Expression 

  | Minus Expression Expression

  | Multiplication Expression Expression

  | Div Expression Expression

  | Expo Expression Expression

  | Neg  Expression 

  | Variable Identifier deriving Show



generateOp :: Maybe Float -> Maybe Float -> (Float -> Float -> Float) -> Maybe Float
generateOp Nothing _ _ = Nothing

generateOp _ Nothing _ = Nothing

generateOp ( Just expr1) (Just expr2) op = Just (op expr1 expr2)



eval ::  Store -> Expression -> Maybe Value 

eval store (Literal l) = Just (l)

eval store (Addition expr1 expr2) = generateOp (eval store expr1) (eval store expr2) (+)
```

hi i'm beginer in haskell i want your help in my studie project
when i execute that commande i have a probleme . i have no idea why !!

```
*Main> eval store ( Literal 5 )


<interactive>:107:6:

    Couldn't match expected type ‘Store’

                with actual type ‘[([Char], Integer)]’

    In the first argument of ‘eval’, namely ‘store’

    In the expression: eval store (Literal 5)
```

Comment: Change the type of `generateOp` to `(Float -> Float -> Float) -> (Maybe Float) -> (Maybe Float) -> Maybe Float`, and the definition can be simplified to `generateOp = liftA2` (where `liftA2` is defined in `Control.Applicative`. Fancy type classes aside, changing the type also reflects normal prefix order, where the operator comes before the arguments.

Comment: Also, `findVar` is just reimplementing the built-in `lookup` function.

Comment: I think you meant `type Store = Map.Map Identifier Value` as well. `data Store = Map Identifier Value` just defines a type that wraps a pair of values with a constructor named `Map`, unrelated to the `Map` type constructor.

Answer (score 4):

A list of tuples is not a `Map`; you need to use `fromList` to create an actual map object.

```
store = Map.fromList [("x", 1), ("y", 2)]
```

Providing explicit type annotations would catch this type of error sooner, as the following wouldn't typecheck:

```
store :: Store
store = [("x", 1), ("y", 2)]
```